# Return datalist linkbutton text value into a label

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a datalist with a linkButton showing warehouse location numbers, when clicking on this datalist linkbutton I need the selected location number to show in a label. I am stuggling to make it happen; here is `enter code here`my code:

```
    <asp:DataList ID="LocList" runat="server" RepeatDirection="vertical" 
RepeatColumns="18" RepeatLayout="Table" OnItemDataBound="DataList_ItemDataBound"> 
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lkLoc" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("WHLOC") %>'  ForeColor="#000" Font-Names="calibri" Font-Size="Medium" onclick="lk_Click" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
<asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server"></asp:Label>

    Protected Sub lk_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    For Each dli As DataListItem In LocList.Items
        Dim LkVal As String = CType(dli.FindControl("WHLOC"), LinkButton).Text.ToString
        lbl1.Text = LkVal.ToString
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with using below code it will helps you:

.aspx code:

```
  <asp:DataList ID="LocList" runat="server" RepeatDirection="vertical" 
RepeatColumns="18" RepeatLayout="Table" OnItemDataBound="DataList_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="DataList_ItemCommand"> 
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lkLoc" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("WHLOC") %>'  ForeColor="#000" Font-Names="calibri" Font-Size="Medium" onclick="lk_Click" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
<asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

.aspx.cs code here:

```
   Protected Sub DataList_ItemCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As DataListCommandEventArgs)

        Dim lkLoc As LinkButton = CType(e.Item.FindControl("lkLoc"), LinkButton)
        lbl1.Text = lkLoc.Text

    End Sub
```